# How do I find an image of function?

Tags: functions

I just started to learn this topic.
I got this function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x+4 & x \le 0 \\ -4x+6 & x > 0 \end{cases}$$
How do I find the image of the function?
I found that the domain of the function is true for every X.
Could someone clarify how do I find the image of this function?

Thanks.

Please excuse my English as it is not my main langauage.

Comment: Just draw the graph and look at it?

Comment: @HansLundmark I drew the graph, how do I conclude $$Im(f)$$ from it?

Comment: Do you know the definition of an image?

Comment: @Michael The set of all outputs a function can give?

Comment: Are there any gaps in the values on the y axis? If there are, those values are not in the image.

Comment: @Paul So, because the domain of the function is basically every X, can I say that the image of the function is F: R->R?

Comment: No you can't. The function $f(x) = 1$ is defined for all x but the image is the single number $1$. You need to ask yourself, for a number y on the vertical axis, is there a corresponding x that goes with it or can you draw a horizontal line from y to the graph? For my example, I cannot do that for any number except y = 1.

Comment: Your inputs are on the $x$-axis, right? So where would you look to see the outputs?

Comment: So if I understand correctly the image of the function is $$(6, -infinity)$$

Comment: Yes, I would say $(-\infty, 6]$ where the square bracket says that 6 is included (when $x = 0$). Using a round bracket means the 6 is not included.

Comment: @Paul: $f(0)=4$, not $6$.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark oops. Should be $(-\infty, 6)$ as 6 is not a value of $f(x)$. I wrote $f(x)$ down wrong with a 6 not a 4 when I graphed it, sigh.